# Identify this larvae that lives on a musrhoom?

Tags: species-identification, mycology, arthropod

I was in the forest near the Rhone river in France and I uncovered some mildewy wood bracket fughi (Ganoderma) on a fallen willow tree. It was a scene from a sci-fi film. some arthropod larvae of 2-3cm had built cocoons within a web, and the cocoons were empty and the larvae were wondering around on the mushroom.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Neat! Please update with location and approximate size of larvae and fungi. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, added that info, Rhone Alps, France, 2-3cm. perhaps I have to take one captive in controlled conditions and see.